# Paginating data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

There is a jbutton in my Jpanel. When I clicked it, it loads up my Jtable, sometimes a query return so many records (500 rows). So I want to restrict it to 5 records.

When query return I want to count it; if it's higher than 5 then Jtable shows up only first 5 record, when user click Forward button it will shows up next 5 record. When user click Back button it will show previous 5 record.

How can I do this? Is there any example for this with TableModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest implementing a "Paged" `TableModel` which provides a window onto the entire dataset and methods for moving forwards and backwards throughout the data.  This way you do not require two `List`s to store the data but rather a single `List` holding all data along with a marker to your current position; e.g.

```
public class ImmutablePagedTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private final List<MyBusinessObject> allData;
  private final int pageSize;
  private int pos;  

  public ImmutablePagedTableModel(List<MyBusinessObject> allData) {
    // Copy construct internal list.  Use ArrayList for random access look-up efficiency.
    this.allData = new ArrayList<MyBusinessObject>(allData);
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if the model has another page of data or false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean hasNextPage() {
    return pos + pageSize < allData.size();
  }

  /**
   * Flips to the next page of data available.
   */
  public void nextPage() {
    if (hasNextPage()) {
      pos += pageSize;

      // All data in the table has effectively "changed", so fire an event
      // causing the JTable to repaint.  
      fireTableDataChanged();
    } else {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }    
  }

  public int getRowcount() {
    return Math.min(pageSize, allData.size() - pos);
  }

  // TODO: Implement hasPreviousPage(), previousPage();
}
```

As 00rush mentions a more ambitious approach would be to use a `SwingWorker` to stream in the data in the background.  You could still use the paged `TableModel` approach for this; you'd just need to ensure that appropriate `TableModelEvent`s are fired as you append to the end of the `allData` list.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to load a large table, you may want to use a SwingWorker (details [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)) thread to load the table in the background.  Loading a table with 500 rows should not be a problem.  You can then put the data into a suitable object format and pass it to your TableModel.

If you decide to use a List for example, in your table model you could have two lists:

```
List allData
List viewData
int startIndex
```

The viewData list is what is referenced by the getValueAt(..) method in your implementation of the TableModel interface.  The viewData list is always a subset (bound by startIndex, of length 5) of allData.  When the user clicks "Next", your action listener could call a method on the Table model that increments startIndex by 5 (or whatever).  You then regenerate your viewData instance so that it is the appropriate 5 row subset of allData, and call fireTableChanged().  This will be easy if you have extended [AbstractTableModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) in the first place.

This should be pretty straightforward to implement.  I think its better than making a database call every time you want to get the next set of data.  IMHO, its better to take a little bit more time upfront to preload the data.

Comment: Adamski's approach above is more elegant than using 2 lists.  I would still recommend using a SwingWorker to pre-load the data though.